# docker exec fails to find /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, debian

I need to append a repository within `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The file exists within the docker container.
the command I am executing is:

`docker exec -u 0 -it my_container echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

Somehow it fails saying: `-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory`

Interestingly, I am able to execute:

`echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`
after getting into the container with `docker exec -u 0 -it my_container /bin/bash`

I am wondering why is the 1st command is not working.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using aspnet:8.0 AS base, try:

```
RUN sed -i 's/^Components: main$/& contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources
```

Comment: man, how on earth did you found this?

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate it with

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo chmod 755 /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `>>` is the culprit here. I had to put the whole command within quotes. This worked for me:

`docker exec -u 0 -it my_container bash -c 'echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'`

Comment: ...because your local shell processes the `>>` before it runs the command.  Also remember that any change you make like this will get lost as soon as your container exits: you want to do this in your Dockerfile, not a `docker exec` debugging shell.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Yup making those changes.